# With SurveyMonkey is it possible to give questions canonical names?

Tags: survey, surveymonkey, canonicalization

I a writing a web hook that captures data from a SurveyMonkey survey and exports it to a CMS in a more structured format.  The data I get from Survey Monkey is very wordy.  Instead of something nice like

```
{
  "dateCreated": "2019-01-10T04:03:56+00:00",
  "paymentIssue": "Not Answered"
}
```

I instead get the actual wording of the question as the key

```
{
  "Date Created": "2019-01-10T04:03:56+00:00",
  "Please select an option that best categorises the payment issues you experienced": "Not Answered"
}
```

If the client later decides to change "Please select an option that best categorises the payment issues you experienced" to say "Please choose an option that best categorises the payment issues you experienced" then my code will break.  There are about 60 questions in the survey, some of which I need to pull specific fields from (company number, customer name, etc) and I am concerned that this is going to be very brittle.

Is there a way in Survey Monkey I can assign canonical names to questions so that, when the data is exported I get a more concise and consistent set of data, instead of the free-form data I currently get? At least for the specific questions I need to extract answers from.

Comment: Are you interfacing directly with the SurveyMonkey API, or are you using a 3rd party library or integration?

Comment: Using Zapier's web hooks to get the survey data sent to a web hook.

Comment: SurveyMonkey does not support labeling of questions at this time, therefore the Zapier integration is forced to use the question title.
My suggestion would be to use the SurveyMonkey API directly, since you'll get the question IDs with the response data.